# How to clear contents of other cells if I delete the main data of which the other cells depend on?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code for my worksheet now. When I input the data in Column E, the returning values such as dates of the comment "new" will work fine in Column B, D and F respectively.

However, when i delete the data on Column E, the returning values at Column B, D and F stays there.

How can I have them cleared if I delete the data that I've entered in Column E?

Much Thanks!

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 10000
    If Cells(i, "E").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Date
        Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
        Cells(i, "D").Value = "NEW"
        Cells(i, "F").Value = "NEW"
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean , that if you clear Column E contents, then clear the contents in columns B,D and F, then use the code below

(However, why do you need to scan the entire rows, on every cell change ? )

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i               As Integer

For i = 2 To 10000
    If Cells(i, "E").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Date
        Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
        Cells(i, "D").Value = "NEW"
        Cells(i, "F").Value = "NEW"
    Else
        If Cells(i, "E").Value = "" Then
            Cells(i, "B").ClearContents
            Cells(i, "D").ClearContents
            Cells(i, "F").ClearContents
        End If
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

**Improved code:** only run the code if a cell inside Column E is changed, in that case modify the value only for cells in Columns B,D and F for that row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WatchRange                  As Range
Dim IntersectRange              As Range

' can modify it to your need, also using dynamic last row with data
Set WatchRange = Range("E2:E10000")
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

' check values in Column E, only if cells in Column E are modified
If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    Dim i               As Integer

   ' change value only for relevant row change
    i = Target.Row

    If Cells(i, "E").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Date
        Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
        Cells(i, "D").Value = "NEW"
        Cells(i, "F").Value = "NEW"
    Else
        If Cells(i, "E").Value = "" Then
            Cells(i, "B").ClearContents
            Cells(i, "D").ClearContents
            Cells(i, "F").ClearContents
        End If
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried the above mentioned method, however, it hangs my program everytime I tried to enter new data. Thank you. (:

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!